# Rails 4.2 not reading Environment Variables for Database.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, environment-variables, ruby-on-rails-4.2

My database.yml file does not seem to be picking up the environment variable correctly.  When I put the password in directly, there are no issues, so I know it's not a password problem.  I've also restarted the server.

Also, when I launch IRB on the server and type in ENV["DB_PASSWORD" it is returned:

```
    2.2.0 :001 > ENV["DB_PASSWORD"]
 => "tej-wir-alt-od-yirf-aj-yam-yis-ed-an-buc"
```

database.yml

```
production:
  database: myapp
  username: root
  password: <%= ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] %>
  host: localhost
  adapter: mysql2
  port: 3306
  pool: 15
  timeout: 5000
```

.bashrc

```
export MYSQL_DB=tej-wir-alt-od-yirf-aj-yam-yis-ed-an-buc
```

Comment: How is your app being served (passenger, unicorn etc) ? Depending on how that is setup, .bashrc might not be used

Comment: I'm using passenger - .bashrc seems to be working as I also have ENV variables for my secret_key_base

Answer (score 4):

You can set variable in .profile because it will load every time while you will reboot server.

You can add with following step:

open `sudo nano ~/.profile`

Then add variable

```
export DB_PASSWORD=tej-wir-alt-od-yirf-aj-yam-yis-ed-an-buc
```

Then reload profile with

```
. ~/.profile
```

And it will be work.

Comment: Thanks!  Moving the following from __.bashrc__ to __.prorfile__ worked for me (Rails 4.2, deploying to Apache on Digital Ocean) export RAILS_DATABASE_PASSWORD='mypassword'
export SECRET_KEY_BASE=secretkey

Comment: Worked with passenger gem.